# Test class execution in Veeva orgs

Tags: deployment, code-coverage, veeva

**#badpracticealart**

The previous team on a project informed us that:

> It is a standard for production orgs (with Veeva installed) to have
>   successful deployments where code coverage <75%.

The previous team's org's code coverage is 8% in prod, and they had no problems deploying to prod.

---

Questions:

1. In Veeva orgs, do test classes execute at all during production deployment? Can we deploy to production with testLevel=NoTestRun? Or do they execute, and it's just that the 75% threshold is overlooked?
2. In Veeva orgs, if test classes have failures, will prod deployment still succeed?

Comment: Sorry all, this is an INVALID question. The org does NOT have Veeva as an installed package. Someone has just named everything in the org as "Veeva". Moderators, please can you delete this question?

Comment: Question still is valid though might not apply to your scenario but valid when it comes to managed package apps installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veeva is a managed package application .For Managed package application test classes for all the classes inside the Veeva package will run during package Installation and after that you need not worry if there are failures and your overall coverage is less .

A managed package application has a namespace and the test execution for that is taken care by the vendor . If a veeva vendor did not have proper coverage for their code , the package creation itself would have failed .

For all other code that you write , its important to have a code coverage greater than 75% else deployment will fail .

The test classes that you maintain outside the package provided class should not fail else deployment will fail .You cannot use testLevel=NoTestRun and still succeed with deployment .

Also testLevel= RunLocalTests is recommended as it will run all tests excluding ones provided by managed package .

As a best practice use testLevel= RunLocalTests and if you are looking to push specific tests you can do it with testLevel= RunSpecifiedTests (Use this as last resort. Helpful in bigger org where it takes huge time to deploy and validate ).

Note that when you do RunSpecifiedTests , each of your classes should exceed > 75% test coverage else the deployment will fail .

Comment: Sorry Mohit, my question is INVALID. Our org does NOT have Veeva as an installed package. Someone has just named everything in the org as "Veeva". I've asked moderators to delete my question.

Comment: I would still advice to keep this question open .It may not be valid for your scenario but it is one of the most misunderstood things